# Denominators of rational polytopes in terms of hyperplane coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, lattice-polytopes

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a convex polytope in $\mathbb{R}^n$ given in the form $\mathcal{P} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n\colon A x\leq b \}$. Suppose that the entries of $A$ and $b$ are integers. Then it is well-known that $\mathcal{P}$ is a *rational* polytope, i.e., its vertices have rational (but not necessarily integral) coordinates. We might be interested in how far $\mathcal{P}$ is from being a lattice polytope. So let $\kappa$ be the biggest denominator appearing in any coordinate of a vertex of $\mathcal{P}$.

Finally, suppose further that the entries of $A$ and $b$ are bounded in absolute value by some $m$. Since there are only finitely many possible $A$ and $b$ in this case, we must be able to bound $\kappa$ in terms of $n$ and $m$. But I have no clue how $\kappa$ behaves. Which leads to my question.

**Question**: In this situation, what is an upper bound for $\kappa$ in terms of $n$ and $m$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x$ be a vertex of $\mathcal{P}$. By [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule), there is an $n \times n$ matrix $C$ such that each coordinate of $x$ is an integer multiple of $\frac{1}{|\det(C)|}$, and the absolute value of each entry of $C$ is bounded by $m$.  Therefore, by [Hadamard's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_inequality), $$\kappa \leq m^n n^{n/2}.$$

The proof actually shows that $\kappa$ does not depend on $b$. Of course, the largest *numerators* appearing in $x$ will depend on $b$.